# How does the OPCW insure that the scientists hired by the FFM are objective, independent and competent?

Tags: international, chemical-weapons, transparency

> **The experts chosen by the FFM were described as internationally
> recognised, coming from three different countries, working
> independently and using “different methodologies and approaches for
> their analyses in order to produce more comprehensive results”.** The
> positioning of the Douma cylinders, as seen by the FFM and in photos
> and videos posted online, suggested they had caused holes by hitting
> concrete roofs, with one of them ending up on a bed in the room below.
> Using computer modelling and other techniques, the experts concluded
> that the damage at the scene could indeed have been caused by the
> cylinders crashing into the roofs.

https://brian-whit.medium.com/the-douma-chemical-weapons-investigation-and-the-role-of-ian-henderson-ab44399a9070

I was reading this and I was wondering how the Organisation for the Prohibition of Chemical Weapons (OPCW) Fact-Finding Mission (FFM) insures that the scientist they hire to write the reports are objective, independent and competent. Is this process publicly disclosed, and how do they even insure that the scientists are fully independent? Is there a peer-review process where every finding is shared and submitted for peer-review?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure *peer-review* is really a thing in this context.  This is
**not** a scientific academic research setting and asking about the specific peer review process being followed, unless this is merely a terminology issue, makes it seem as if there is an intent to discredit the OPCW for not following what is an inapplicable process in this context.

Having said that, the various findings *are* [available for public viewing](https://www.opcw.org/fact-finding-mission), including by experts in the field.

re.  Douma, there are a number of items, but this seems the final report:

[Note by the Technical Secretariat: Report of the Fact-Finding Mission Regarding the Incident of Alleged Use of Toxic Chemicals as a Weapon in Douma, Syrian Arab Republic, on 7 April 2018](https://www.opcw.org/sites/default/files/documents/2019/03/s-1731-2019%28e%29.pdf)

Anyone can review the findings.  I don't know how that compares to the level of access to raw data that is customary in academic scientific papers.

I didn't see anything about team composition.  That might be elsewhere, it might be absent.  It might also be an intentional omission to safeguard team member security.

**The question one has to ask oneself however is:  how likely is a large scale deception to discredit the Syrian regime to survive the test of time and repeated scrutiny?  How many witnesses need to recount war crimes before one accepts that those war crimes probably did happen?**

Why did Europe decide to accept so many Syrian refugees in 2015, if there wasn't real concern for their actual safety?  It seems far-fetched that Germany would accept 1M refugees to hand the US a PR win against Syria and Russia, for example.

Is the Syrian government of such a benign nature that carrying out chemical attacks is implausible?  Their regional peer and ideological fellow traveller (both follow or used to follow Baathist ideology), Iraq, did this in the late 80s.  And they have prior history massacring large rebel areas, in [Hama, 1982.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_Hama_massacre)

In regards to this question also:  if the team members were not reputable, shouldn't the affected governments have a trace of their official objections?

p.s. here's also an [annex about OPCW methodology](https://www.opcw.org/sites/default/files/documents/SAB/en/Final_Report_of_SAB_TWG_on_Verification_-_as_presented_to_SAB.pdf) - and I guess credibility, considerations.

---

I didn't DV.  Asking how these processes are carried out, and [what is in place to ensure objectivity](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72352/what-mechanisms-are-available-to-bear-witness-in-an-explicitly-non-partisan-fa) is on topic for this site.  But it doesn't hurt to apply a bit of Occam's Razor to this type of consideration, before believing overmuch in conspiracies and cover ups.

If someone knows can point to references on how international monitoring and fact finding teams are chosen in an adversarial context  - country A and country B are opposed and each has a vested interest in "spin" -  that would be a great additional answer to this Q.  Need not concern OPCW itself.  You may need to consider the context of mission setup however:  the monitoring team put together to scour Iraq for WMD in the 90s was put together in a very different power ratio than this team in Syria, for example: OPCW worked for UN and Russia has a lot of say there.